# How is $rootScope controlled across multiple Angular modules?

Tags: angularjs

I have a large AngularJS application that I have organized by seperating differnet key features into their own modules.  For example, I have 2 modules called "myApp.Alerts" and "myApp.Header".

The "myApp.Alerts" contains a factory, some directives and a controller that is used to manage an "Alerts" page in my app.

The "myApp.Header" is also a module that contains directives and a controller for managing just the header of my application.

Now in my header I want to have a some Alert related functionality (basically push notifications like facebook or twitter) so if the user changes something on the page with Alerts then it will get updated in the header as well.

My "myApp.Header" uses DI to get the "myApp.Alerts" with

`angular.module('myApp.Header', ['myApp.Alerts'])`

I use a factory in "myApp.Alerts" to GET, POST, PUT, DELETE Alerts. When one of these actions are completed, such as a DELETE Alert, I am trying to use events to trigger the "myApp.Header" to update as well.

So if a call to `MyAlertsFactory.deleteAlert(alert)` is made then I do something like `$rootScope.$broadcast('updateAlert:delete')`, then in my header I have a directive that has `$scope.$on('updateAlert:delete')`.

The problem is that the event is never handled by my listener. After some debugging I realized that my 2 modules each instantiated a different version of my factory. Rather than being a singleton that is shared throughout the lifespan of the app, there are 2 different singletons.. one that is controller with "myApp.Header" and the other "myApp.Alerts". This causes the events to never trigger on the correct service.

Is there a correct way to "link" together modules so they share the same $rootScope and other factorys, services, providers, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should be doing generally, it would be better to think about why you have separate modules that need to communicate with each other in this way.

Although, here is a sketch of a solution:

Have a window element that stores every module rootScope, and this is updated in your app.run blocks.

Write a wrapper for triggering events on rootScope in the app you want to push to the other modules. This wrapper function executes the event on every rootScope and calls digest on each. You must not forget to call digest.